# Where is Wheat?

Tags: discussion, users

I'm not sure to what extent this question can be answered, but it's one I'm desperately curious about.

I followed some meta questions and links to chat logs, but I still can't figure out what the dispute was about. This is not intended to dig-up dirt or expose anyone or anything. So, please keep this page clean and directed to this point:

*Is there anything, we, the community can do, to bring Wheat Williams back?*

His valuable contributions remain as unsearchable ghost answers, but if he's upset and left, then we won't be getting any more. Maybe that's selfish, but I feel sad to lose him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we all feel the same way about Wheat — he was a great asset.  Unfortunately he seems to have made his decision and I think we should respect it.

Ultimately, it seems that he didn't like SE's focus on Answers-as-answers.  He had a few posts that, while often containing great information, were unrelated or tangential to the question.  When users commented on this, downvoted, etc. he reacted rather strongly.  I think he would prefer a place more discussion-oriented rather than direct Q&A.

**Please note that this is all my interpretation of what happened.**  I don't mean to put words in his mouth; obviously I don't know his mind.

I was also not privy to some final conversations he had with other mods, and I believe they should be kept private anyways.

---

I think the best we can do is to keep focusing on great Q&A and attract new experts.  The Stack Exchange model is proven to work and create great content, even if it's not always for everyone.